# PSFTP Recursive Delete

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to set up an automated SFTP backup from my local machine to a remote NAS.

I've got a batch script that calls PSFTP. I'm looking to mirror a local directory to a remote directory. PSFTP doesn't have a mirror command, but it can do a recursive PUT. So I thought I'd try to do delete the directory on the SFTP server and then do the recursive PUT, which would accomplish the same thing. PSFTP doesn't support a recursive DEL, though, nor can you do RMDIR on a non-empty directory.

So, in a Windows batch environment, how can I delete the remote directory before I upload it?

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using a scripting instead of GUI for your automated backup, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (it has both a command-line scripting and GUI).

WinSCP supports both [recursive upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) and and [recursive rm](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm).

See also general [guide for automating SFTP using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but I've seen your name so much times on WinSCP site that I cannot not say - welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not shure if it's really good idea to delete all to then put it back on again, on larger directories this will need time and power. i too don't know psftp, but if you are able to use windows command rmdir, you may use xcopy too? and if so maybe xxcopy may be a even better solution, very powerfull and free for private use.

Comment: Can't use xcopy because the transfer is going over SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a free GUI-based solution to do SFTP:

http://www.duplicati.com/

Took a little while to get it going, but to make it do SFTP, you actually need to tell it SSH. Also, it seems to want to create a folder on the remote server. So, let Duplicati create the folder instead of choosing an existing folder and it'll accept the entry. I have it set to do a full backup and only keep one backup, thus accomplishing what I set out to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plink to execute any command on server, including rm -r